# PhpStorm fails with git

Tags: git, phpstorm

When I try to git fetch or any other command I get errors.

```
10:35:18.905: [DocGen] git -c core.quotepath=false pull --progress --no-stat -v --progress origin master
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@xxxx.githost.io: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The problem is PhpStorm don't ask me the id_rsa key password.

If I do this in the command line it works:

```
C:\work_dev\Project (master)
λ git -c core.quotepath=false pull --progress --no-stat -v --progress origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Username/.ssh/id_rsa':
From xxxx.githost.io:certification/DocGen
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
Already up-to-date.
```

This was working before I update PhpStorm, also when I tried to revert to using the old version know it doesn't work too.

Comment: Do you use ssh keys for access and ssh-agent to cache them? It may be that your command line is aware of them but phpstorm's is not.

Comment: no i don't use ssh-agent

Comment: For reference purposes: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38582

Comment: If you move or remove C:\Users\ your username \.PhpStorm2017.X (depends on the version you use) and start PhpStorm without importing settings, can you still reproduce it?